# Changing woocommerce related products text with tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, gettext

I'm currently using [Change Related Products Heading adding the product name in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138672/11987538) answer code but instead of the get_the_title
I want to be getting the tags of the product

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: But i wrote the  code  but when i change to get_the_tags i get an error    Hi

I m currently using the following code but instead of the get_the_title
I want to be getting the tags of the product

add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_related_products_title', 10, 3 );

function change_related_products_title( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {

    if( $text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce' ){

        $translated = esc_html__( 'These go well with', $domain ) . ' ' . esc_html( get_the_title() );

    }

    return $translated;

}

Answer (score -1):

```
$term_list = array();
$terms_data = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );
if( count($terms_data) > 0 ){
    foreach($terms_data as $termdata){
        $term_id = $termdata->term_id;
        $term_name = $termdata->name;
        $term_slug = $termdata->slug;
        $term_link = get_term_link( $termdata, 'product_tag' );
        $term_list[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
    }
    $term_list = implode( ', ', $output );
    echo $term_list;
}
```